# Blazorise Grid: Columns are not next to each other

Tags: c#, asp.net, grid, blazor, blazorise

I want to display two ApexCharts next to each other. They are always being displayed beneath each other, is my Grid set up wrong?

```
<Row Margin="Margin.Is4">
    <Column ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is12">
        <Card Background="Background.Light">
            <CardBody>
                <CardTitle Size="3">
                    Card title
                </CardTitle>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
    </Column> </Row> <Row Margin="Margin.Is4">
    <Column ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is12">
        <Card Background="Background.Light">
            <CardBody>
                <Column ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is6">
                    <ApexChart TItem="Software"
                               Title="Order Net Value">
                        <ApexPointSeries TItem="Software"
                                         Items="Softwares"
                                         Name="Gross Value"
                                         XValue="@(e => e.Developer)"
                                         YAggregate="@(e => e.Count())"
                                         OrderByDescending="e=>e.Y"
                                         SeriesType="SeriesType.Bar" />
                    </ApexChart>
                </Column>
                <Column ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is6">
                    <ApexChart TItem="License"
                               Title="Order Gross Value">

                        <ApexPointSeries TItem="License"
                                         Items="Licenses"
                                         Name="Gross Value"
                                         SeriesType="SeriesType.Pie"
                                         XValue="@(e => e.taken)"
                                         YAggregate="@(e => e.Count())"
                                         OrderByDescending="e=>e.Y" />
                    </ApexChart>
                </Column>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
    </Column> </Row>
```

I also tried making the Columns for both of the Charts only 5 wide, but they are still displayed beneath each other.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I forgot to add another row to my inner grid around my Charts:

```
<Row Margin="Margin.Is4">
<Column ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is12">
    <Card Background="Background.Light">
        <CardBody>
            <CardTitle Size="3">
                Card title
            </CardTitle>
        </CardBody>
    </Card>
</Column> </Row> <Row Margin="Margin.Is4">
<Column ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is12">
    <Card Background="Background.Light">
        <CardBody>
            **<Row>**
            <Column ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is6">
                //Chart
            </Column>
            <Column ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is6">
                //Chart
            </Column>
            **</Row>**
        </CardBody>
    </Card>
</Column> 
</Row>
```